# Open Graph Action's Custom Property - type Array

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a problems with the correct passing parameters when publishing OG action. The action has custom property 'profile' of type Array. I want to pass 2 elements to this parameter.
How can I generate link for this?

I have tried these variants:

FB.api("/me/APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION?OG_OBJECT=LINK_TO_OG_OBJECT&profile[]=1&profile[]=2",....)

FB.api("/me/APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION?OG_OBJECT=LINK_TO_OG_OBJECT&profile[0]=1&profile[1]=2",....)

They don't work - FB returns error.

Help please

---

I tried to pass array as a JSON and as escaped JSON.

```
var q = new Array();
q.push(*VALUE1*);
q.push(*VALUE2*);

q = $.toJSON(q);
```

tried this:  '...profile[]='+q+'...'  ,   '...profile='+q+'...'
and this: '...profile[]='+escape(q)+'...',  '...profile='+escape(q)+'...'

and tried to pass q as Object in JSON (escaped).

Doesn't work

Comment: hi, I am having a similar issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Currently no. No any answer from FB guys and here

Answer (score 0):

Without having tried it yet, I would assume like in most cases with the Graph API your supposed to pass array data as a JSON …?